# C++ - Wait for user input but print the next line

Tags: c++

So I am making a GUI with ascci, I would like to wait for user input but print the last line of ascci border. As of now it will wait for user input and then print the last ascci border line. Is there anyway to fix this?

Example of what I want:

Login Screen

```
======================================================

        Welcome to Bank Beta 0.1
        ------------------------

        (1)Login
        (2)Create Account


        USER INPUT HERE

======================================================
```

Example of what I am getting:

```
======================================================

        Welcome to Bank Beta 0.1
        ------------------------

        (1)Login
        (2)Create Account


        USER INPUT HERE
```

Here's my code:

```
void login ()
{
    cout << "======================================================" << endl
        << "\t\tWelcome to Bank Beta 0.1" << endl
        << "\t\t------------------------" << endl << endl
        << "\t\t (1)Login" << endl
        << "\t\t (2)Create Account" << endl << endl;
}
int main()
{ 
    int loginChoice;
    login();
    cin >> loginChoice;
    cout << "======================================================" << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: code added, i relise that I have got the last block of the boarder after the input as to get the input to show before the boarder end.

Comment: add the line after "cin >> loginChoice" to your login function and that would do it. Also, beware of endl as it will flush your stream. Try and use "\n" until the last line, where you could flush.

Comment: I think ncurses may do what you want

Comment: If i add cin to my login functuon it will promt the user and not allow the boarder to print until the user has inputed?

Comment: std::cin and std::cout are separate input and output streams so yes, if you "out(put)" the border before "(c)in(put)" the user choice it will get print. Just try it: put the cin after all your "couts". Beware: if you're trying to make the user put his output "above" the bottom border this will not work!!!. Code is sequential and cin "blocks" code execution. There are (non portable) ways of setting the cursor position but IMHO it's not worth it. If you're trying to make GUIs you'd do better checking ncurses, as said above.

Comment: As @sweerpotato said: ncurses may do what you want.

Comment: What system and console are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are working on a console based GUI, i suggest using some sort of cursor movement functionality. This will save you a lot of time in the alignment of "objects" too.

Here is the code you will need to move the cursor for both win and unix

```
#ifdef _WIN32

    #include <windows.h>

    void gotoxy(int x, int y)
    {
        COORD p = { x, y };
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), p);
    }

    #else

    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <term.h>

    void gotoxy(int x, int y)
    {
        int err;
        if (!cur_term)
        if (setupterm(NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &err) == ERR)
            return;
        putp(tparm(tigetstr("cup"), y, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

#endif
```

You can remove either of them if you don't need platform independence, but having them both does no harm. now the interesting part:

```
void login ()
{
    cout << "======================================================" << "\n"
    << "\t\tWelcome to Bank Beta 0.1" << "\n"
    << "\t\t------------------------" << "\n\n"
    << "\t\t (1)Login" << "\n"
    << "\t\t (2)Create Account" << "\n\n";
    gotoxy(0, 7);
    cout << "======================================================" << "\n";
    gotoxy(0, 6);
    cout << "\t\t";
}
int main()
{ 
    int loginChoice;
    login();
    gotoxy(0,8);
    cin >> loginChoice;
    _getch();
}
```

The writing and reading are now independent of each other and you can also mess around with all the positions a lot more easyer.

Comment: ncurses also seems to do this job in a platform independent way: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html

Comment: as a side note, in the main, shouldn't it be `gotoxy(0,8);` instead of `goto(0,8);` ?

Comment: yes, Ploutox is right, my mistake 'gotoxy(0,8)' in main